# python 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'from_bytes'

Tags: python, attributeerror, nonetype

Please help, this has been driving me mad.

```
def get_pinstatus(*args):
    ser.write("p".encode())
    time.sleep(1) # wait for buffer to fill up
#   for i in range (16):
    value= ser.read(1)
    new_value = int.from_bytes(value, byteorder='big')
```

It's fairly simple code, it's going to read 16 seperate bytes from serial and I need to convert each one to an 8bit int. If I type the last 4 statements into the python command line it works perfectly, just not when in the function.
No matter how I format the code, I always receive the following error:

```
new_value = int.from_bytes(value, byteorder='big')

AtrributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'from_bytes'
```

Comment: Maybe consider `struct.pack` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere you have redefined `int` as None.

Answer (score 1):

As well as what Daniel's mentioned - which is the cause of your error, you'll also be better off using the `struct` module, so instead of:

```
value= ser.read(1)
new_value = int.from_bytes(value, byteorder='big')
```

You can use:

```
import struct

int_values = struct.unpack('>16B', ser.read(16))
```